# Soundness of propositional logic proof

Tags: logic, proof-verification, propositional-calculus

Let 
$$\begin{align}
A1&=(p\implies (q\implies p))
\\
A2&=(((p\implies (q \implies r)) \implies ((p\implies q)\implies (p\implies r)))
\\
A3&=((\neg p \implies \neg q ) \implies ((\neg p \implies q ) \implies p))
\end{align}
$$

Let $S=(\mathcal{L}_{\{\neg,\implies,\wedge,\vee\}},\{A1,A2,A3\},\text{MP})$ be our system.

> $\bf Theorem$
>
> If $\Gamma \vdash \gamma $ then $\Gamma \vDash \gamma$.

**Proof.**

I'll do this by induction on the length $n$ of the proof for a formula $\tau$.

Base case. $n=1$.

Then the proof is

$$1.\tau\quad \text{Hypothesis.}$$

or 
$$1.\tau\quad \text{Axiom.}$$

In the first case, we have that $\tau\in \Gamma$, thus trivially, $\Gamma \vDash \tau$. In the second case, $\tau$ is a tautology, again, obviously, $\Gamma \vdash\tau$.

Now, let $\tau$ be a formula with a proof of length $n+1$.

Then that line looks like

$$n+1.\, \tau\quad \text{Axiom}$$

or

$$n+1.\, \tau\quad \text{MP (i,j).}$$

Where $i<j\leq n$.

On the first case, $\tau$ is a tautology, in the second case, we have formulas $\alpha=(\beta \implies \tau), \beta$ with proofs of length $i,j\leq n$ respectively, so we have that $\Gamma \vDash \alpha,\beta$.

Let $v$ be a valuation such that $v(\Gamma) = \{1\}.$ We have that $v(\beta \implies \tau)= 1$ if and only if $v(\beta)=0$ or $ v(\tau)=1$, but $\Gamma \vDash \beta$, therefore $v(\tau)=1$, and $\Gamma \vDash \tau$ Q.E.D.

Have  I covered all the cases?

Comment: You have to show that if $\Gamma \vDash \alpha \to \tau$ and $\Gamma \vDash \alpha$, then $\Gamma \vDash \tau$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I managed to show that, thanks! Is my proof correct now?

Comment: Yes. it works...